# Jquery Ajax NyroModal Page Reload after Succes

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have site running Jquery, Ajax, PHP, and an HTML form. It uses two pages.

Pages...

Example.php & Processexample.php

When you click the edit button on example.php a form pops up in the NyroModal window posting to Processexample.php and allows you to edit customer data that's posted using Ajax.

After user clicks save on Porcessexample.php a SQL update is made and a success message is posted back to the Modal Box (end-user).

Here are the issues...

1. I can't get the NyroModal window to close after (data) success is called on processexample.php. I tried setting the Timeout in JQ/Javascript below but error occurs.

**setTimeout("$.nyroModal.close()", 4000);**

1. How do i get example.php page to display updated data automatically, or have the page reload after #send button is clicked and success is displayed in modal window.

**HTML Form Code on processexample.php**

```
<form id="AjaxForm" name="AjaxForm" action="#" method="post">

<input name="submitform" type="hidden" value="1" 

<button id="send">Save Client</button>
```

**JS Code on processexample.php** --> See bold text in code where issue is.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {


    $("#AjaxForm").submit(function() { return false; });


    $("#send").on("click", function(e){

        var idval    = $("#client").val();
        var calval    = $("#view").val();
        var emailval  = $("#customer_email").val();
        var nameval   = $("#customer_name").val();
        var phoneval  = $("#customer_phone").val();


        var msgval    = $("#customer_note").val();
        var msglen    = msgval.length;
        var mailvalid = validateEmail(emailval);


        if(mailvalid == true && msglen >= 4) {
            // if both validate we attempt to send the e-mail
            // first we hide the submit btn so the user doesnt click twice
            $("#send").replaceWith("<em>sending...</em>");

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'saveclient.php',
                data: $("#AjaxForm").serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    if(data == "true") {
                        $("#AjaxForm").fadeOut("fast", function(){
                            $(this).before("<p><strong>Success! Your information has been updated.</strong></p>");
                            **setTimeout("$.nyroModal.close()", 4000);**
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work this out myself. Use location.reload(); after the success call.